# Como traduzir «floss»?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês, termos-em-inglês

Tenho a seguinte frase:

> The main motivation behind MariaDB was to provide a **floss** version of MySQL, in case Oracle goes all corporate with MySQL. It's worth noting that Monty was vocal against MySQL acquisition (via Sun's acquisition) by Oracle.

Duas perguntas:

- Como eu poderia traduzir a palavra ***floss***, de forma que faça sentido e se encaixe, sendo o mais próximo possível do termo original?

---

- Traduzir a frase superior como:

> A principal motivação por parte do MariaDB foi fornecer uma versão ***floss*** do MySQL, no caso da Oracle se tornar totalmente corporativa com o MySQL. Vale ressaltar que Monty foi contra a aquisição do MySQL (via aquisição da Sun) pela Oracle.

Seria compreensível?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*FLOSS* é a sigla para *"free/libre and open-source software"* (seria algo do tipo **"*software* livre e de código aberto"**).

Basicamente, o [software livre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) como conceito possui [várias denominações](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_terms_for_free_software)* , entre elas: *free software*, *open-source software*, e a sigla *FOSS*, que significa *free open-source software*.

* <sup>*não vou entrar nas questões filosófico-políticas, nem tampouco técnicas e/ou históricas, pois nenhuma delas vem ao caso*</sup>

A palavra *free* em inglês pode significar tanto "grátis" quanto "livre", por isso surgiu a sigla *FLOSS*, usando a palavra *libre*, que em Espanhol significa "livre" no sentido de "liberdade" (*"freedom"*). Ou seja, o termo *free/libre* serviria para [retirar a ambiguidade](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/floss-and-foss.html) e enfatizar que o termo refere-se à liberdade, e não ao preço.

---

Na área de tecnologia (pelo menos no Brasil) não é comum traduzir termos estrangeiros, incluindo as siglas. Neste caso específico, eu sugiro colocar a sigla em maiúsculas (*FLOSS*, como é mais usada geralmente), caso a audiência esteja familiarizada com o termo.

Porém, no caso específico de *open-source*, é comum também usar os termos "software livre" e "código aberto". Aí fica à sua escolha:

> ... fornecer uma versão *software* livre/de código aberto do MySQL

Ou até mesmo:

> ... fornecer uma versão *open-source* do MySQL

(Já que *open-source* é mais uma expressão que nem sempre é traduzida).

Alguns textos ainda usam somente o termo "livre", portanto ficaria:

> ... fornecer uma versão livre do MySQL

---

Conforme lembrado por [@Peixoto nos comentários](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4774/como-traduzir-floss/4775?noredirect=1#comment12593_4775), os termos "livre" e "código aberto" não são a mesma coisa (um software pode ter apenas uma das características, ou ambas). E *FLOSS*, no caso, significa ambas (*"free/libre"* e *"open-source"*).

Apesar disso, algumas (muitas?) vezes os termos são usados erroneamente (usa-se um quando quer se referir ao outro ou a ambos, em todas as combinações possíveis). Sugiro então usar *FLOSS* e incluir um glossário ou uma nota explicativa (ou no caso do texto estar na internet, um link para a wikipedia ou qualquer outro artigo que explique o termo).

Comment: Então seria como um sinônimo? *Floss* de *Free*? Então não tem problema manter como está?

Comment: @unknown Eu prefiro pensar que FLOSS é apenas uma sigla. Se já tem o mesmo significado de "free" a ponto de ser sinônimo, creio que é de cada um (para mim não é, mas tem gente que acha que é). Como eu disse, acho que cabe a você decidir qual a melhor tradução dentre as opções apresentadas (pois depende de quem vai ler a tradução, se estão familiarizados com os termos, qual vai fazer com que todos entendam, etc). Se você acha que manter como está (FLOSS) pode causar estranhamento, eu incluiria um glossário ou uma observação explicando o termo. Enfim, depende do contexto. Boa sorte!

Comment: @unknown No caso do pt.stackoverflow, creio que a maioria deve conhecer o termo, então eu deixaria "FLOSS" (em maiúsculas, como a sigla é geralmente usada) e incluiria um link para a wikipedia ou o artigo que eu coloquei na resposta (https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/floss-and-foss.html)

Comment: Free e FLOSS seriam diferentes. Um software pode ser Free (Livre ou grátis) mas não de código aberto. Já FLOSS, seria livre e de código aberto).

Comment: @Peixoto De fato, free e open-source são coisas diferentes, embora muitos achem que não são. Editei a resposta com esta informação, obrigado!